# LC Circuit with a DC input

Tags: waves, electricity, electric-circuits, oscillators, electronics

[image]

In the previous LC circuit, if we connect one end with a DC input voltage and the other with ground, what does the oscillating output wave look like?

I know that if the capacitor was initially charged and no voltage is connected, the oscillating output will have a continuously decreasing amplitude due to the internal resistance of the circuit.

But in that case there is constant DC voltage on both L and C so there is no way decreasing amplitude occurs because energy is continuously fed to the circuit.

Comment: The components in schematic diagrams such as the one in your question conventionally represent _ideal_ components.  If the resistance of the wires in a physical circuit play a significant role in some question, then there should be a resistor symbol (or maybe more than one resistor symbol if it matters) that represents the wire resistance.  I must confess though, I don't know the convention for distinguishing the "real" components from the "parasitic" ones in a schematic.

Comment: If you connect an _ideal_ voltage source in parallel with the capacitor and the coil in your diagram, then there is no "oscillating wave."  The voltage between any two points on the same wire (same circuit _node_) is zero by definition (but not in a real, physical circuit where wires have resistance), and the voltage between the terminals of a voltage source is constant by definition.

Comment: FYI, the time-varying behavior of an electronic circuit after a switch is thrown or a voltage is applied or etc. is called its _transient response_.

Comment: Related? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/373431/104696

Answer (score 0):

First of all, where are you taking the output? If it's at the same nodes that you are putting in the input, your output voltage signal will just be the same as your input voltage signal no matter *what* is going on in your circuit.

The imdepence of an inductor is $Z_L=i\omega L$, and for a capacitor it's $Z_C=1/i\omega C$.

For DC, $\omega=0$, so the inductor acts like a short, and in this idealized case you'd just get infinite current through the inductor. Power is being put into the circuit, but only in the DC mode. If you include resistors to represent internal resistance of the circuit, any initial energy excitations around the natural frequency would dissipate since you're not putting in more energy at those modes.